# Visual Studio 2010 Solution Crashes when Opening

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The "Preparing Solution" window come up as normal.  Then about two seconds after it goes away Visual Studio crashes.  It only happens to one specific solution.  How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Is this a WPF solution? I had some crashes happen in both VS2008 and VS2010 when some very specific .xaml were opened at the project opening. Removing the .user file to reset the opened files solved the problem.

Answer (score 38):

After deleting all the `.suo` files and `.user` files from the project, I'd start VS with logging, and investgate from there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx

Comment: My VS 2010 would always stay "busy" after opening a particular solution. Deleting the `.suo` fixed this.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible some VS settings that are incompatible with your current installation state cause the crash. Delete the `.suo` file, if that doesn't help, run `devenv.exe /ResetSettings`.